No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Error while fetch works fine during login with the same cors options
I'm trying to send a post request to my server using fetch but it is constantly getting blocked by cors policy. However when I used fetch during user login, it was working fine. And this issue popped up once I deployed the entire project on vercel and tested it there. I tried it previously using axios as well, however it was showing the same error.
Here is the request that I sent from the frontend
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        dispatch(setTotalPrice(totalPrice));
        
        try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    "https://merncafe-server.vercel.app/",
                    {
                        mode: "cors",
                        credentials: "same-origin",
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                        body: JSON.stringify({priceBreakdown}),
                    });
                console.log(response);
                
            }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

Here is my /server/index.js
app.use(cors(
    {
        origin: ["https://merncafe.vercel.app"],
        methods: [
            "POST",
             "GET"
        ],
        credentials: true,
        allowedHeaders: [
            "Content-Type",
        ]
    }
));

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/assets")));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "public/assets");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({storage});

app.post("/auth/register", upload.single("picture"), register);

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

app.post("/pay", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const url = await createOrder();
        res.redirect(url);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
})

const prices = [];

app.post("/", async(req, res) => {
    const priceBreakdown = req.body.priceBreakdown;
    prices.push(priceBreakdown)
})

And this is the error I was getting
Access to fetch at 'https://merncafe-server.vercel.app/' from origin 'https://merncafe.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

However, I didn't get any such error at the time of login using the same headers
const login = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    const loggedInResponse = await fetch("https://merncafe-server.vercel.app/auth/login", {
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include",
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    });
    const loggedIn = await loggedInResponse.json();

Here is my vercel.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "index.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/"
      }
    ]
  }

What could possibly be the issue here? And how do I fix it?

Hi, Can you please share version.json as well.
